# ChefSpec test if python modules were installed

Tags: chef-infra, chefspec

I found a way in [InSpec](https://www.inspec.io/docs/reference/resources/pip/) to test whether or not python modules have been installed with chef, but I'm using `ChefSpec` and I can't find an alternative. Does anybody know if there's a way to check if a certain pip module has been installed with `ChefSpec`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ChefSpec doesn't test side effects, so you don't check the module itself, you look at what resources were scheduled for execution. If you're using poise-python, that would mean a test like:

```
it { is_expected.to install_python_package('foo') }
```

Comment: thanks! This is definitely what I want, but when I include it in my tests I get an error `NoMethodError:
       undefined method 'find_resource' for "(my test context)":String` - it points to the line with your statement as having the error (I replaced `foo` with an actual package). Do you know what might be causing this issue?

Comment: Using `is_expected` assumes you have `subject { ChefSpec...converge(described_recipe) }`. If you use a different `let` variable, you'll need to adjust the RSpec-y bits.